# Creating a right hand in Graphics3D to illustrate the right hand rule

Tags: graphics3d

I would like to make a small right hand with fingers that curl to illustrate the right hand rule in `Graphics3D`. Does anyone know if this is possible?

For an example of what I'm looking to plot, see https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/137975/how-to-visualise-the-direction-of-torque

Is there something like "drawing tools" for `Graphics3D`?

-David

Comment: You could probably find a 3D model online, or is that not acceptable for your application? e.g. https://www.google.co.uk/#q=thumbs+up+3d+model+free

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but how would a "3D model" of a hand be used in graphics3d?

Comment: Pick a format on [this page](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/3DGeometryAndModelingFormats.html) and see the examples.

Comment: Thanks so far guys, you have been a significant help. I've never used a ".stl" file before. 

I have imported 3d model of a right hand, and combined with my graphics3d plot using the show command. The problem I now have is that the hand is much to large, is at the wrong location, and is at the wrong orientation. Are these things specifiable?

Comment: In real life: [img](http://i.stack.imgur.com/iepdl.jpg) (Marseille, France)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's easiest to control the position and size of all 3D objects if they are combined in the same `Graphics3D`. For an `STL` file, this could be done as follows (I didn't want to look for a hand model, so I chose the seashell model built into `ExampleData`, since it's also chiral):

```
Export["g.stl", ExampleData[{"Geometry3D", "Seashell"}]];

g = Import["g.stl"];

Graphics3D[{
  Map[{Apply[RGBColor, #], Arrow[Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, #}]]} &, 
   2 IdentityMatrix[3]],
  EdgeForm[], FaceForm[Orange, Brown], GeometricTransformation[
   g[[1]],
   Composition[
    TranslationTransform[{0, 1, 0}], 
    RotationTransform[Pi/2, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0}], 
    ScalingTransform[{.5, .5, .5}]
    ]
   ]
  }, Lighting -> "Neutral"
 ]
```

[image: seashell]

Here I called the imported `STL` graphics `g`. To insert it into the existing `Graphics3D` containing three axis arrows, I strip away the `Head` by doing `g[[1]]` which then contains only the polygon data. Also, I added the basic machinery to move, resize and rotate the seashell in the 3D scene, by wrapping `g[[1]]` in a [`GeometricTransformation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/GeometricTransformation.html) containing a [`Composition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Composition.html) of the three geometric operations. In particular, the [`ScalingTransform`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ScalingTransform.html) can be used to adjust the size, before shifting the object to the desired location with the [`TranslationTransform`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/TranslationTransform.html).

Comment: +1 for my new favorite coordinate system marker :D

Comment: I think that this answer will solve my problems, though I'll post back latter when I have tried to integrate it into my code.

Comment: This is the hand that I am using right now: http://www.123dapp.com/123C-3D-Model/Thumbs-Up/721284

Comment: If anyone has a better one, pls post the link. It would be better to have a hand that is less "clenched" than the one I posted, one with space between the fingers and palm so you can see them wrapping around a bit clearer.

Comment: This worked for me, thanks!

Answer (score 7):

```
myThumb = Import["123dapp.com/123C-3D-Model/Thumbs-Up/721284"];

Show[myThumb, 
 Graphics3D[
  {
   {Red, Thick, Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, -20}}]},
   {Green, Thick, Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, -20, 0}}]},
   {Blue, Thick, Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {-20, 0, 0}}]},
   {Text[Style["x", Italic, Blue, 24], {-22, 0, 0}]},
   {Text[Style["y", Italic, Red, 24], {0, 0, -22}]},
   {Text[Style["z", Italic, Green, 24], {0, -22, 0}]}
   }
  ]
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: This answer would benefit a lot from a working URL for the STL.

Comment: http://www.123dapp.com/123C-3D-Model/Thumbs-Up/721284